# Is it "RAW-Legal" to combine TCE and SCAG Bladesingers?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, optional-rules

[Tasha's Cauldron of Everything](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/tcoe) updated Bladesinger wizards (originally from Sword Coast Adventurer's Guide) in a few key ways. For one, it expanded the Extra Attack feature to allow casting a cantrip in place of one of your attacks. I really like this addition and think it's great for character concepts that seamlessly blend spellcasting and swordplay.

It also, however, changed the Bladesong feature from "twice per short or long rest" to "proficiency bonus times per long rest." Most players these days don't seem to really use short rests, so this is probably meant to be an improvement, or at least a simplification to reduce bookkeeping. But I think short rests are a fun and important mechanic. The new version of this feature makes me feel like I need to study up in the school of divination just to decide when in the adventuring day to activate my bladesong!

Here's the thing: the introduction to Tasha's Cauldron of Everything says "Everything in this book is optional." Does this mean you can take individual parts of the TCE Bladesinger, but otherwise use the SCAG Bladesinger? That is, **can you create a Bladesinger that regains their two uses of bladesong after a short rest, and can also swing a scimitar and shoot a *fire bolt* as part of the same Attack action?**

I know TCE is a big stack of of "this is up to your DM," but it is allowed in Adventurer's League, so I still think it's fair to consider what's "rules as written" according to Tasha's.

This question can probably also apply to other things that were introduced in one book, then re-introduced "optionally" in another book, like the Artificer (which, ignoring Unearthed Arcana, was originally printed in an Eberron book, then was also expanded in TCE)

Comment: Is the question specifically about AL? Because if so, I'd make that more explicit. "RAW" and "AL legal" might not be the same answer.

Comment: It's not just AL! I just figured I'd bring it up because as far as I'm aware, AL generally disallows things like homebrew and houserules (but does allow a bunch of "optional" rules from Tasha's on an individual basis, and also apparently the book in general)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

### The most recent printing or publication replaces earlier ones

In general, if there are multiple versions of the same thing, like a race or class description, the latest publication prevails.

For example, the hobgoblin race in *Mordenkainen Presents* replaces the earlier one from *Volo's Guide to Monsters*. Likewise, the Tasha's version of the Bladesinger class replaces the earlier one from *Sword Coast Adventurer's Guide*.

Wizards announces this on a [D&D Beyond page about legacy content](https://www.dndbeyond.com/legacy):

> The introduction of Mordenkainen Presents: Monsters of the  Multiverse to the Dungeons & Dragons game has revised older content. Going forward, any content that does not reflect the latest rules and lore will be categorized as Legacy Content.

Likewise, the [Adventurer's League](https://dnd.wizards.com/ddal_general) Players Guide advises on the first page under "**What Rulebooks should I use?**"

> You can use non-optional rules found in the Player’s Handbook, the Basic Rules, and all the books listed below. **If a rule has been reprinted in a newer resource, you must always use the latest printing.**

The "books listed below" include both *Sword Coast Adventurer's Guide* (SCAG) and *Tasha's Cauldron of Everything*. So, you cannot cherry-pick and combine the best from different iterations of a class to min-max something stronger. You are supposed to use the latest version of the class, exclusively. In this case, Tasha's, as it was printed later than SCAG.

As @Someone_Evil points out, in this specific case the SCAG also [received errata](https://media.wizards.com/2021/dnd/downloads/SCAG-Errata.pdf), so that its Bladesong feature now uses the same rule for how often you can use Bladesong as Tasha's:

> **Bladesong (p. 142)**. The two sentences after the bulleted
> list now read, “You can use this feature a number of times equal to your proficiency bonus, and you regain all expended uses of it when you finish a long rest.

(What you negotiate with your DM as homebrew house rules is an entirely other matter, of course).

Answer (score 9):

### No. You take one version of the class or the other

You are right that TCE contains optional content and for most part you can pick individual rules and use them but a class or subclass is a logical whole, the balance of a class is built around using it in its entirety so you cannot “mix and match” different versions of the same class from different sources.

Different versions of the same class usually contain subtle modifications, with one feature made stronger and another adjusted in turn by being made slightly weaker to keep the overall balance. Being able to choose and combine traits would allow you to pick all the strongest versions of individual features, making the class significantly stronger overall.

Note that TCE also gives you *Optional Features* - these **can** be selected individually and separately from each other as TCE explicitly states, there is no equivalent statement that would apply to regular class features, therefore I think the designers’ intention was that these shouldn’t be picked individually, otherwise they would have stated it as they did for *Optional Features*.

Adventurers League has some additional rules of their own, if the same content can be found in different versions in several rulebooks, you **have to** use the latest one, there’s no flexibility involved here. If you’re playing in a non-AL game, it’s up to DM which sourcebooks they allow but mixing class features like this is neither allowed RAW, not in AL.

Comment: Of note, and perhaps strengthening your final arguement, there is an optional replacement for the Beast Master archetype for the Ranger and the structure around that is distinctly different to that around the Bladesinger.

Comment: I upvoted this. I think it is a useful complementary answer, to look at it from the perspective of balance. (Even though it is not a RAW answer as asked for).